# Azure mobile EasyTables connection string

Tags: c#, sql, database, azure

I am fairly beginner in here, so any help would be much appreciated :)

So, I created a SQL Database and I want to connect EasyTables to it. Apparently the automatic option has been removed and I have to do it manually.

I followed "How can I add a connection string manually" page but it lead me to nothing.

Where should i create the connection string, and what to put in the value field?

Or if there is any tutorials out there for the new way please tell me :)

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you have followed tutorial: [How can I add a connection string manually](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/02/26/Changes-to-data-connections-UX.html).

The Easy Table connection should like this:

SQL Database Connection String format

```
Data Source=tcp:{your_SQLServer},{port};Initial Catalog={your_catalogue};User ID={your_username};Password={your_password}
```

1. {your_SQLServer} Name of the server, this can be found in the
   overview page for your database and is usually in the form of
   “server_name.database.windows.net”.
2. {port} usually 1433.
3. {your_catalogue} Name of the database.
4. {your_username} User name to access your database.
5. {your_password} Password to access your database.

**Add the connection string to your Web App**

In App Service, you can manage connection strings for your application by using the Configuration option in the menu.

To add a connection string:

1. Click on the Application settings tab.
2. Click on [+] New connection string.
3. You will need to provide Name, Value and Type for your connection
   string.

   - If your are adding a connection string to a SQL Azure database choose
     SQLAzure under type.
   - If your are adding a connection to an Azure Storage account, chose
     Custom under type.

**NOTE** If you are adding a connection string because you are planning on using the Easy API or Easy Table features, then the connection strings used by this features expect the following specific names:

- > Azure SQL database: MS_TableConnectionString
- Azure Storage account: MS_AzureStorageAccountConnectionString

For example, this is my connection string:
[image]

When you have configured this, go to Easy table, click `Add`  to add the table name in your Azure SQL database.
[image]

You can find that esay table has connected to my Azure SQL database now and we can see the data in the table.

**Update:**

1. You should first add the connection string in the configuration followed the format provided for you.
2. Then go to Easy Table, configure Easy table API:

[image]

Choose the 2:

[image]

When it done, you can add table in your SQL database, please follow my steps in above.

**Note:**

> Your connection string name must be: MS_TableConnectionString.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, so the value is the connection string then. Thanks. I put it in, got the server_name, port which is 1433,catalog and username and password and clicked save. However when i go to EasyTables page, i still "Click here to learn how to connect a database". Is there something else missing or what?

Comment: When editing on the value field this msg is always there: value is a required property on all connection strings

Comment: @Abdelrahman I updated more details. If you have followed the value format and connection string name, just ignore the message " value is a required property on all connection strings ".

Comment: @Abdelrahman If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Leon for your patience and time, it is working :)